# Format countdown timer to use a leading zero digit when less than ten seconds

Tags: android

My countdown timer needs to display seconds in the correct format. It is currently all correct, until it gets to counts less than 10 seconds.

At that point it displays as follows: `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`. I need it in the format of `09 08 06 05 04 03 02 01`.

Here is the timers code:

```
private CountDownTimer timer(int time)
{
    CountDownTimer a = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) 
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String clock;
            clock = "" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)/60)%60 + ":" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60);
            Clk.setText(clock);
            // mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            alarm.start();
            Clk.setText("00:00");
        }
    }.start();

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using String.format

```
int remaining = ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60);
clock = String.format("seconds remaining: %02d .", remaining);
```

Comment: It will crash. You cant set string to int

Comment: @Waqas cheers, I did not notice all that embedded string stuff

Comment: so what should i use that is the most effective ?

Answer (score 2):

```
int seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
Clk.setClock(String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60, seconds % 60));
```

This will display:

```
12:34
07:45
00:10
00:09
00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the seconds you receive have value less than 10 if so append 0 in front of them while doing `setText` like

```
if((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 < 10)
    clock = "" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)/60)%60 + ":0" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60);
else
    clock = "" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)/60)%60 + ":" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clock = "" + (String.format("%02d",(millisUntilFinished / 1000)/60)%60) + ":" + (String.format("%02d",((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60));

            Clk.setText(clock);
```

Use

```
String.format("%02d",9) //provides 09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int minutes = 15;
int seconds = 1;
String display = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, secconds);
System.out.println("display= " + display)
```